# How to set a global property for all components in an application

Tags: vue.js

I'm making a vuejs component but as I'm not very experienced I'm not sure how to implement the idea I have.
My idea is to create a reusable component that will have a string URL property for **all instances** on the application, ideally when registering, representing this `rootURL`.

I would like to let the users of my component set this `rootURL` when doing:

```
import myComponent from 'my-component';
Vue.component('vue-headful', vueHeadful);
```

Then on every component I could to combine `rootURL` with a `path` property that would be different for every instance of the component like:

```
<a href="{rootURL} + {path}"/>
```

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add an instance property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) like this:

```
Vue.prototype.$rootURL = 'https:://mydomain.com/root'
```

and then use it in your components as `this.$rootUrl` or `{{ $rootUrl }}` in a component's template.

Comment: I ended up using your method so I marked your answer as solution. Also I later discovered how vue-lazyload does this https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload/blob/master/src/lazy.js#L31 but I didn't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mixins` which will be available in your all components.

```
<template>
   <div>{{ rootUrl }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import commonData from '../Mixins/commonData'
export default {
 name: 'Test',
 mixins: [common]
}
</script>
```

You can define your `rootUrl` data property in `commonData.js` file

**commonData.js**

```
export const commonData = {    
    data() {
        return {
            rootURL : "http://example.com"
        }
    }    
};
```